# Using Bower in a VM with puppet to run python-nvd3

Tags: node.js, puppet, bower

I'm trying to set up a VM to use python-nvd3 and using puppet to provision the machine. I've got node.js/npm to go in ok but then I get an error trying to install packages using bower:

```
  package { 'bower':
    provider => npm
  }
  exec { 'install d3':
    command => '/usr/local/bin/bower install d3#3.3.8',
    require => Package["bower"]
  }
  exec { 'install nvd3':
    command => '/usr/local/bin/bower install nvd3#1.1.12-beta',
    require => Package["bower"]
  }

err: /Stage[main]/Infinite_interns::Box::Tm351d001r/Exec[install d3]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: /usr/local/bin/bower install d3#3.3.8 returned 1 instead of one of [0] at /vagrant/modules/infinite_interns/manifests/box/tm351d001r.pp:39
```

If I ssh in to the VM, and try to run a `bower` command I get a y/n prompt to ask if I want to allow error logging. In this case I don't want to and I don't want my provisioner to fall over because it can't answer the question (if this is the problem that's causing the above puppet error).

Comment: One problem initially was a missing dependency - git needs to be installed; however, installing git, testing from VM commandline to check `bower install` now works (it does), the puppet error above still appears.

Comment: Hmm.. I wonder: maybe vagrant is trying to run the installation using sudo rather than as a (lesser) user? How do I handle that in vagrant/puppet?

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the `CI` environment variable to `true` or use the `config.interactive=false` bower flag to avoid interactive operations. Example:

```
exec { 'install d3':
  command => '/usr/local/bin/bower install d3#3.3.8 --config.interactive=false',
  require => Package["bower"]
}
```

Reference:
https://github.com/bower/bower#running-on-a-continuous-integration-server

Comment: Ah, but this does not set the `CI` variable, yes?

Comment: Tried that - doesn't seem to make a difference: same error message? Maybe another issue?

Comment: Arghh.. just gone in to have a look - no git:-(

Comment: Hmm.. added git but still get error; I can install from ssh command line but the vagrant/puppet thing throws same error still.

Comment: what if you run 'puppet apply' with '--debug'?

Comment: @Emyl Erm.. I'm right on the edge of my cut, copy, edit and paste abilities here! puppet magic happens courtesy of vagrant as far as I'm concerned!

Comment: @Emyl I managed to get it to run using the switches: --config.interactive=false --allow-root